# FoldList or NestList of a function

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I have two lists `list1 = {a, a, a}` and `list2 = {a, b, c}`, and a function `f`.

I want `z1=f(a f(a f(a)))`, `z2 = f(c f(b f(a)))`. I managed to get `z1` but no luck with `z2`. Any suggestion.

```
list1 = ConstantArray[a, 3]

z1 = Nest[f[a #] &, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list2 = {a, b, c};
z2 = Fold[f[# #2] &, 1, list2]
```

> f[c f[b f[a]]]

Comment: Alternatively: `Fold[f[Times[##]] &, 1, {a, b, c}]`

Comment: Even shorter: `Fold[f@*Times, 1, {a, b, c}]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1; Nest[f[# list2[[i++]]] &, 1, Length @ list2]]
```

> f[c f[b f[a]]]

And yet another way of saying `Composition[f, Times]` (credit @Mr.Wizard):

```
 Fold[f[1 ##] &, 1, list2]
```

> f[c f[b f[a]]]